# Materialize SideNav fixed doesn't fit in div

Tags: html, css, materialize, sidenav

I'm trying to make a screen using CSS, DIVs and Materialize SideNav. What I'm trying to do is something like this:

[image]

This is my code:

```css
#header{
     background-color: lightgray;
     width:100%;
     height:10%;
     text-align: center;
}

#left-menu{
     float:left;
     width:20%;
     background-color: red;
}
#content{
     float:left;
     width:100%;
     background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
</head>
 <body>
  <div id="header">
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td style="width: 33.3%";"><div><img src="img/main_logo.png" width="300px" height="60" style="vertical-align: middle"/></div></td>               
     <td style="width: 33.3%;";><div style="font-size:32px;" align="center">MAIN TITLE</div></td>
     <td style="width: 33.3%";></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
  <div id="left-menu">
   <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav fixed">
    <li>
     <div class="userView">
      <img class="background" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
      <a href="#!user"><img class="circle" src="http://placehold.it/350x300"></a>
      <a href="#!name"><span class="white-text name">John Doe</span></a>
      <a href="#!email"><span class="white-text email">jdandturk@gmail.com</span></a>
     </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>First Link With Icon</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">Second Link</a></li>
    <li><div class="divider"></div></li>
    <li><a class="subheader">Subheader</a></li>
    <li><a class="waves-effect" href="#!">Third Link With Waves</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div id="content">
  </div>
```

But my output it's not what I'm expecting, the SideNav does not fit in the DIV. Instead it is extending further into the header as well, furthermore, the content div has no width and the SideNav shows a scroll bar. I need to figure out what I am doing wrong.

This is my result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What I tried in your code is to put absolute position in header, left-menu and the content styling (css).

[image]
See the code below

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #header{
               left: 0;
               right:0;
               top: 0;
               position:absolute;
               background-color: lightgray;
               width:100%;
               height:10%;
               text-align: center;
            }

            #left-menu{
                position:absolute;
                left: 0;
                top:92px; bottom: 0;
                width: 400px;
                background-color: red;
            }

            #content{
                 position: absolute;
                 left: 400px;
                 top:92px; right:0; bottom:0;
                 background-color: blue;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <table>
                <tr>
                <td style="width: 33.3%";">
                    <div>
                        <img src="img/main_logo.png" width="300px" height="60" style="vertical-align: middle"/>
                    </div>
                </td>               
                <td style="width: 33.3%;";>
                    <div style="font-size:32px;" align="center">MAIN TITLE</div>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 33.3%";></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div id="left-menu">
            <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav fixed">
                <li>
                    <div class="userView">
                    <img class="background" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
                    <a href="#!user"><img class="circle" src="http://placehold.it/350x300"></a>
                    <a href="#!name"><span class="white-text name">John Doe</span></a>
                    <a href="#!email"><span class="white-text email">jdandturk@gmail.com</span></a>
                </div>
            </li>
                <li>
                <a href="#!">
                    <i class="material-icons">cloud</i>First Link With Icon</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#!">Second Link</a></li>
                <li><div class="divider"></div></li>
                <li><a class="subheader">Subheader</a></li>
                <li><a class="waves-effect" href="#!">Third Link With Waves</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <h1>Your content goes here</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not working, the menu it's outside the DIV https://imgur.com/0keLB0a